# keywords mining from given text in python

Tags: python-3.x

List of keywords to be mined:

```
keywords_list = ['object-oriented programming','information security industry','python','java programmer']
```

This is a text where the above keywords have to mined:

```
text = "***Python*** allows programmers to define their own types using classes and also ***python*** are most often used for ***object-oriented programming*** .***Python*** has also seen extensive use in the ***information security industry***, including in exploit development."
```

From the above text we have to mine the given keywords which may or may not be in the text. Also we have to count the number of keywords present in the text.

Output:

```
mined_words = ['python','object-oriented programming','information security industry']

count = [3,1,1]
```

Comment: You can remove punctuations, split by space, and then loop through each word and check if it is `in keywords_list`. Also, create a dictionary to store the counts associated with the keywords.

Comment: It's always a good idea to add what code you've already tried, or tell us what you have tried implementing when asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

```
count_list = [text.lower().count(kw) for kw in keywords_list]
mined_text = dict(zip(keywords_list, count_list))
output = sorted(mined_text, key = mined_text.get, reverse=True)
count_output = [mined_text.get(out) for out in output]
```

In the future, it's better to post your progress and ask for advice. For now, hope this works for you.